# Use unthreadsafe, unmanaged code in Windows 8 App store application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps, unmanaged

I have a Windows desktop app that launches worker processes that contain unmanaged code.  The unmanaged code is not thread safe - I am wrapping it in a process to fully isolate it.

I would like to create a new version for the Windows App (metro) marketplace.

Anyone have any suggestions on doing the same from a metro application?  There doesn't appear to be any way to really launch a separate process (at least, without something hacky that requires a separate install).  I could wrap it in a AppDomain, but I don't think that provides the isolation I need.  I could PINVOKE ONE instance, but the thread-safe issue makes it a issue for more than one instance.

Comment: If you should not be running 2 in parallel just don't do that... I'm not exactly sure what is the problem?

Comment: Alexei - each process is connecting to a stream and recording it.  The desktop version records many at one time.   It would be great to just thread this, but the original code is (very) un-threadsafe.

Comment: I see. Consider making your requirements clear as is it looked like sequential execution is just fine from original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Store apps cannot launch arbitrary processes, but they can launch out-of-proc components from within their app-package. You could wrap your unsafe code in a Windows Runtime EXE component.

There is a sample demonstrating this at [Creating a Windows Runtime EXE component with C++ sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Creating-a-Windows-Runtime-ed84af9d)

Also make sure that the existing processes don't depend on API (such as System.AppDomain) that are unavailable to Windows Store apps. MSDN has documentation on which .Net and Win32 API are available in Runtime apps at [.NET for Windows Runtime apps](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=227049) and [Win32 and COM APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/br205757.aspx)